# Formula for every 3 columns

Tags: google-sheets

I need help to improve my google sheet. I work in a school and the students are organized by houses. Each house in each class and subject get points based in the performance of the children, then teachers input the points in a Google Sheet and every Friday we summarize them in an Assembly.

I'm trying to improve the spreadsheet without changing many things, so I added some formula for adding automatiquely the points added by the teachers. Now I'm looking to add the points for every week to get a total so I'm looking for a formula to add the numbers in the row 15 of the spreadsheet. I would need to add every three colums until the end of the year (B15, E15, H15.... for the orange house for example). Any formula so it can be added automatiquely in B28? The same for the other houses (blue, red). Could it maybe filtering the view to show only those colums then select many at once, but I'm not sure about the strategy to use.

Thank you very much

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18I7XWmQAugyO4cX3HptKzyEF4jR4D5xxdeiC-oSEcQc/edit?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: Welcome! What about `=SUM(FILTER(15:15,2:2=$B$2))` for Akiva, `=SUM(FILTER(15:15,2:2=$C$2))` for David and same `=SUM(FILTER(15:15,2:2=$D$2))` for Hillel? (Not sure what **until the end of the year** means - these formulas sum up everything up to the end of the total row)

Comment: By the way, the idea of tying the calculation to the column number (*for every 3 columns*) might work, but this way of calculating is best avoided: you have to be a hopeless optimist to hope that never in the future will a column be added or removed somewhere in the middle of a wide table or just by chance two columns are swapped.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works pretty nice

Answer (score 1):

I have added a duplicated sheet ("Erik Help"). It contains one formula, in B28:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A28:A30),QUERY(TRANSPOSE({B2:2;B15:15}),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE),0))`

This *one* formula will produce *all* results for B28, B29 and B30.

`TRANSPOSE({B2:2;B15:15})` This will place the B2:2 values directly above the B15:15 values in a horizontal array and then flip them to a vertical array.

`QUERY` will then act on that array to give the three different values in Row 2 along with the `SUM` for each.

`VLOOKUP(LEFT( )    )` will then look up the leftmost character in A28:A30 (i.e., the first letter) within that `QUERY` result and return the value from the second column (i.e., the sum).

If no sum is found, `IFERROR` will return `0` (e.g., at the beginning of a year, before points have been added).

Comment: An elegant solution that would suit any houses...as long as their names start with different letters. If the houses are called, for example, Abigail; Allison; Amelia, then the `LEFT()` part of the formula will have to be changed to something else.

Comment: Correct. I write around the information provided. If there were full names in Row 2 matching those in A28:A30, I'd have simply removed the `LEFT( )`.